# How to store an input(raw_input) in a variable to use it later in Python 2.7.9?

Tags: python, variables, raw-input

I will be more specific, this is a shortened edited bit of my code from my text based game:

```
var = ""
```

class example:

```
def: example2(self):

  raw = raw_input("Enter something")
    if raw == "something":
        raw2 = raw_input("Enter something again")
        if raw2 == "something again"
            pass
```

I want to store the input of raw2 in the variable var because I need that input later in my code. Actually I want to save the input, so I can use it later.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but why not simply `test = raw_input("Put in a word")` ?

Comment: seriously the first google with "python raw_input" answers your question http://www.python-kurs.eu/eingabe.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the '"" raw =' part:

```
test = raw_input("Put in a word")
```